# Python Multiprocessing Pool.map Causes Error in __new__

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

In the simple Python 3 example below where we use the `multiproessing` module to process the list `friends`, what is causing the error:

> TypeError: **new**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'

No error occurs if simply running

```
tom = Friend(tom)
say_hello(tom)
```

Any ideas how we can solve this issue? Thank you!

**Code**

```
import multiprocessing

def say_hello(friend):
    print('Hello', friend.name, '!')

class Friend:
    friends = {}
    def __new__(cls, name):
        if name not in cls.friends:
            cls.friends[name] = super(Friend, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls.friends[name]

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

jack = Friend('jack')
ryan = Friend('ryan')
friends = [jack, ryan]
multiprocessing.Pool(2).map(say_hello, friends)
```

**Full Error Trace**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nyxynyx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Users/nyxynyx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/nyxynyx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 110, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/Users/nyxynyx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 354, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
TypeError: __new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

Comment: @Darkonaut Thanks for catching this. Updated the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an error during unpickling because the `name` wasn't prepared for being passed when recreating the object during unpickling.

It can be already reproduced with:

```
pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(jack))

Traceback (most recent call last): 
  ...
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-9-239857af5731>", line 1, in <module>
    pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(jack))
TypeError: __new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

The solution is to implement [`object.__getnewargs__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__getnewargs__) or [`object.__getnewargs_ex__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__getnewargs_ex__).

> object.**getnewargs**()
>
> This method serves a similar purpose as **getnewargs_ex**(), but
>   supports only positional arguments. It must return a tuple of
>   arguments args which will be passed to the **new**() method upon
>   unpickling.
>
> **getnewargs**() will not be called if **getnewargs_ex**() is defined.
>
> Changed in version 3.6: Before Python 3.6, **getnewargs**() was called
>   instead of **getnewargs_ex**() in protocols 2 and 3.

So in your case:

```
def __getnewargs__(self):
    return self.name,
```

Answer (score 1):

Define `__reduce__` to make objects of `Friend` class pickleable (serializable) to be sent to other processes.

```
import multiprocessing

def say_hello(friend):
    print('Hello', friend.name, '!')

class Friend:
    friends = {}
    def __new__(cls, name):
        if name in cls.friends:
            return cls.friends[name]
        else:
            return super(Friend, cls).__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __reduce__(self):
        return self.__class__, (self.name,)

jack = Friend('jack')
ryan = Friend('ryan')
friends = [jack, ryan]
multiprocessing.Pool(2).map(say_hello, friends)
```

Comment: "Although powerful, implementing __reduce__() directly in your classes is error prone. For this reason, class designers should use the high-level interface (i.e., __getnewargs_ex__(), __getstate__() and __setstate__()) whenever possible." [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__setstate__)

Comment: @Darkonaut You are correct. While both Saim Raza and your solutions both appear to solve the problem described in this question, the problem in my actual code (which this minimal complete verifiable question was simplified from) stemmed from an outdated __reduce__() definition!

Comment: Though the doc states that `__reduce__` is error-prone, it is more intuitive to use and as the doc mentions "is the only option or leads to more efficient pickling or both." in some cases. Pickling through `__reduce__` in the current case mimics Friend(<name>) call. Further, using methods like `__setstate__` have other complications. For instance, defining just `__setstate__` never calls `__init__`  during unpickling.