# How to preserve args for unpickling object without storing them

Tags: python, pickle

I have a class with the following

```
def __init__(self, foo, **kwargs):
    self._foo = foo
    self._bar = []
    # transform foo to become bar
```

I want to pickle and then unpickle an object of this class and have implemented the `__reduce__` method to allow me to do this:

```
    def __reduce__(self):
        return self.__class__, (self._foo,)
```

Ideally I wouldn't want to save foo as an instance variable and would only be using bar, the transformed version of foo. Is there a way that would allow me to unpickle the object using the original args without having to store foo? Perhaps moving the creation of `_bar` to another method?

Comment: Stabbing in the dark here but could you perhaps try to remove `_foo` from the state dictionary? `del self.__dict__['_foo']` once you are done transforming `foo` to `bar`.

Comment: On second thought, if you do not want to store `foo` you do not need to add it to the state dictionary at all. Could you not simply transform `foo` to `bar` without `self._foo = foo`.

Comment: The issue is that I need to store the original args for the reduce function or else I get an error when trying to unpickle an instance of this object as part of multiprocessing. The error is similar to the one mentioned in the below post but occurs when trying to use __init__ rather than __new__ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59828469/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-causes-error-in-new